# I need to convert mpfr real number to gmp bit-integer number

Tags: c, gmp, mpfr

I am writing a program, which operates on integers and floating-points. At first, i used GMP library for them, but GMP doesn't have functions such as sin, cos, exp and others at floating points. So, i switched to MPFR library, and all went file.
But now (after first step of calculation), i need to truncate results, and store them in GMP large integers (mpz_t). MPFR doesnt't have integer function. But my results are in mpfr_t, how can i convert them to mpz_t? (or in mpf_t, then i can convert them to mpz_t for myself).

Answer (score 4):

Oops, sorry, found function mpfr_get_z, seems that is what i want :)